# Parse.com registering for push notification after user login

Tags: parse-platform

I know that to register Parse.com push notifications I have to set it all in appdelegate file. But I am wondering if it is possible to override channels and register to multiple channels after user login in a viewcontroller class.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to by doing something like the following.

```
if(![currentInstallation channels]) {

    [currentInstallation setChannels:@[@"WHATEVER1", @" WHATEVER2"]];
    NSLog(@"Set Channel");
} else {

[currentInstall addUniqueObject:@"objectone" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstall addUniqueObject:@"objecttwo" forKey:@"channels"];
} [currentInstall saveInBackgroundWithBlock:(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

if(!error){
    NSLog(@"subscribed user to both channels");
} else {
    NSLog(@"error subscribing to both channels: %@", error);
}
}];
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He wanted to know if he can register for channels in some other place other than the AppDelegate file. ie only register for channels AFTER a user has logged on, not when an app has started.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is run a shared instance of UIApplication anywhere in your application and then call the registration methods. Like this:

```
    let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

This will present the push notifications dialog asking if they want to allow notifications and then make the call back to the appropriate app delegate method of either `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` or `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

If you are testing on a simulator and not on an actual device `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` will always be called.